# Mysql transactions with no effect

Tags: mysql, transactions

I need to use transactions in a project and it seams that they just want not to work :D
Within navicat editor i wrote this lines:

```
SET autocommit=1;
BEGIN;

select * from product where deleted=0 and name='Juice Coke';

insert into product(name, fk_category, fk_packaging, fk_stock, active, decimals, price, has_special_price, special_price_description, added_date, deleted) 
values ('qaaaJuice Coke','2','4','1','1','2','100.244','1','DESC SPECIAL PRICE','2012-02-28 08:26:47', 0 );

select * from product where deleted=0 and name='Juice Pepsi';
ROLLBACK;
/*COMMIT;*/
```

However it does not make rollback and the insertion remains in table.
Do I need to make some changes on database properties or why do you think it does not work?
Thanks, adrian

Comment: what's the `product` table's storage engine? Transactions are currently supported by InnoDB only.

Comment: is MyIsam, ah only innoDb ...ok, thanks I will make now modifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among storage engines shipped with MySQL only InnoDB tables currently support transactions. Change your table's storage from MyISAM to InnoDB

Answer (score 1):

Heh. You should disable autocommit.

```
SET autocommit=0;
```

Comment: `BEGIN;` disables autocommit (which is set to 1 by default anyway)

Answer (score 1):

You have the autocommit feature enabled on the first line. It finishes the transaction as soon as the database table is updated in any way. Set it to SET autocommit=0;
 and your transactions should be fine!